# how much data represents 1 satoshi? and on entire bitcoin

Tags: raw-data

I mean, how many bits or bytes represents 1 satoshi, the minimun bitcoin portion
and how many bytes represents one entire bitcoin, not a block, a 1.00000000BTC

Comment: Bitcoin value is not proportional to number of bytes.

Answer (score 2):

Bitcoin amount is simply a number in the outputs of transactions, bitcoins themselves don't really exist. For example, in [this transaction](https://blockchain.info/tx/a196032e52c0a9d7a9737ffa212f029bceb9618d0bff5c6dde99ecac4e28bf06), there is this output:

> "addr":"1P3VQasrhmCnViL4sVouxSZiSu1BRWuCvN",
>            "value":6103964

Value is the number of satoshis in the output, these output values are the only representation of bitcoins on the blockchain.

Comment: so, what is stored in the blockchain itself (those thing that has about 128gb of data on my harddrive) whats kind of data, and, what is what miners are mining, those address for store that value? if so, thats mean that miners are mining just "valid" address following an algoritm? (sorry fo so many questions, I need to clarify all of this)

Comment: The blockchain includes scripts and signatures to prove that spending is legitimate, timestamps, references to previous blocks so there is an order, etc. Miners validate transactions and add them to blockchain. Further questions should be made in a separate post :)

Answer (score 0):

There is actually no such an object as a Bitcoin (or a satoshi, or any unit used in Bitcoin). Thus there are no data structures which represent "a Bitcoin".

How Bitcoin actually works is by creating and spending from previous transaction outputs. The amount of Bitcoin is simply just a value assigned to a transaction output.

The blockchain contains the transactions, and each of those transactions contains transaction outputs which it creates, and references to other transaction output which it spends from. That is the data that is stored on your hard drive.

Comment: I think I'm finally understand, so, mining consist on carry on those transactions and producing more valid blocks of transactions or starting-point empty-like transactions, that will becomes new outputs transactions when spend, and distributing the representative values of those transactions to whatever address need, if so, I finish me question and thanks